# UIScrollview inside UIScrollview touch not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, viewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller containing a scrollview with paging horizontally, within each 'page' i have a second viewcontroller with a scrollview for scrolling vertically. In the second viewcontroller i have several other viewcontrollers, containing buttons and webviews for instance. This part is working fine, however since i added the paging scrollview (horizontal) the viewcontrollers inside of the vertical scrollview are not responding to any touch gestures anymore. Did i use to many layers? I have added all of the child viewcontrollers to their parents like so:

```
    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
```

Any suggestions?